# React's single source of Truth with html5 video

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-video

I'm building an app which has a html5 video and several controls that interact with the video and use the video's currentTime.

As I understand, the App component should keep in it's state the currentTime of the video and pass it down to other children (say, a display that shows what second the current time for example).

Suppose I hit a keyboard shortcut to skip the video 5s ahead. That way I would have to update the App state and pass the currentTime down to the component that has the html5 video tag, so it updates itself.

However, when the video is playing, I find that the constantly updating of the App state to be puzzling, since it should then pass the state down to the video, causing a sort of hickup on the video playing.

I was able to correct this using the "shouldComponentUpdate" function, however, the docs recommend against using it, as it may be deprecated in the future. I could mimic the shouldComponentUpdate functionality using my own boolean flags, however that starts to make my code smell bad, it seems I shouldn't be trying to control the state passing flags around.

It seems to me that the "single source of truth" here should be the html5 video currentTime property, but that doesn't seem to fit the state hierarchy that react implies (that the App component should maintain the state and pass it down to the other components)

Should I keep the currentTime as a state of App anyways and try to hack around the video updates so it doesn't jitter and loop?

Comment: Would it be possible to manage the state of currentTime in the video component as opposed to the app component?

Comment: I guess not because the sibling components need to read and write the state, but I'm not really sure, it seems the pattern is to leave it to the parent. Otherwise, it is possible to keep the state in the video component

Comment: very interesting problem, but really the only problem is when the video tells react to change the currentTime, which then ends up changing the video to that time some very small fraction of time into the future, causing bad playback. However you can't turn off updating video's currentTime because then it wouldn't respond to legit updates from sibling components anymore. It sounds to me like you need to be abled to pass some sort of 'sender' with the currentTime, and have the sender itself ignore the change. I'll think about an answer

Answer (score -1):

Either do what the do here, or simply prevent re-inventing the wheel and use it

http://mderrick.github.io/react-html5video/

Comment: I am indeed studying how they solved the problem but I don't like some of the design decisions they took and I'd rather understand the technology I'm using than incorporating a git project with a single main author and 3 other collaborators.

Comment: After you've read and understood their approach, come back and update with some detailed comments on why you don't like their approach.  If you end up doing something different, let me know here what those differences were.